# TextInput with securTextEntry automatically clear

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

**I have an TextInput with secureTextEntry set as true. When I do the following steps this input unnecessarily clear all it's content:**

- Type something in the TextInput
- Make any action to lose focus (as example Keyboard.dismiss())
- Tap TextInput again and type something
- Previously entered text immediately clear and you start typing in an empty field
- Is there a way to disable this strange behaviour and allow user continue typing the password from    a point he stopped?

```
                                    value={values.password}
                                    onKeyPress={({ nativeEvent }) => {
                                        console.log('nativeEvent=', nativeEvent);
                                        if (nativeEvent.key === 'Backspace') {
                                            console.log('Backspace=', pwd + nativeEvent.key);
                                            setTimeout(() => {
                                                setPwd(pwd.substring(0, pwd.length - 1));
                                                setFieldValue('password', sanitizeInput(pwd));
                                                setUserNameIns('');
                                            }, 100);
                                        } else {
                                            console.log('pwd + nativeEvent.key=', pwd + nativeEvent.key);
                                            setTimeout(() => {
                                                setPwd(pwd + nativeEvent.key);
                                                setFieldValue('password', sanitizeInput(pwd));
                                                setUserNameIns('');
                                            }, 100);
                                        }
                                    }}
```